# how can i use css selector to give style only to a first div between two divs of the same kind?

Tags: css, html, selector

I want to give border to the first div with the class block in the code below:

```
<div class="col-md-4 news">
            <h3>News Feed</h3>
            <div class="block">
              <p class="date"><span>15</span>march</p>
              <p><a href="#">serving people from 23 branches all over the nepal</a></p>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
              <p class="date"><span>17</span>march</p>
              <p><a href="#">serving people from 23 branches all over the nepal</a></p>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector for first element with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest

```
.block:first-of-type {
 border: yourborder;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  .col-md-4 .block:first-of-type{
      border:1px solid RED;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the first-of-type pseudo selector for this:

```
.news .block:first-of-type {border:1px solid #000;}
```

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lpnywvo/)

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
.block:first-of-type {
    border:solid 1px #ccc;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `first-of-type` selector. Source [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-of-type)

```
.block:first-of-type {
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ja5rvxrt/)

Answer (score 1):

with following code:

```
.news > div:first-child
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.col-md-4.news h3 + .block{ border:solid 1px #000; }
```